# joining two pandas dataframes on date and

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to join two dataframes however after merging the two dataframes i get NaN for all the columns from one of the DataFrames (Master) but the column heading are there.

Below is the structure of each dataframe

```
b.columns
Index(['Date', 'Ticker', 'Price'], dtype='object')

Master.columns
Index(['Ticker', 'Date', 'Previous Quarter', 'No. Of Shares', 'Action'], dtype='object')

b.dtypes
Date      datetime64[ns]
Ticker            object
Price            float64
dtype: object

Master.dtypes
Ticker                      object
Date                datetime64[ns]
Previous Quarter             int64
No. Of Shares                int64
Action                      object
dtype: object
```

i have tried:

```
M1 = pd.merge(left=b,right=Master, how ='left', left_on=['Date', 'Ticker'], right_on=['Date', 'Ticker'])
```

Comment: So you tried, and then what happened?

Comment: I ended up with the data from b and the columns and headings from master but NaN data

Comment: as I indicated below, this would result if you didn't have any exact matches of the left df key columns in your right df key columns. can you post a couple of rows to your data as a test case?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. Realised my issue this morning. The date columns were in a different formats, which was impacting the merge. Thanks for you're help

Answer (score 0):

this might be expected behavior.
you have specified `how = 'left'` which means you are looking for key combinations from your left dataframe only. If there aren't exact(!) key matches in the right dataframe, you are going to get NaN's in the joined table. You can find more info on this argument [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).

I suspect you have no exact matches in your key columns?

Also, if you specify `left_on` and `right_on` to be the same, you might as well only specify `on`.